# GeckoWebBrowser frame navigate

Tags: c#, winforms, frame, gecko

Is it possible to navigate some frame in the document? somthing like WebBrowser

```
HtmlWindow frame = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Frames["main"]; 
frame.Navigate("http://" + webBrowser1.Url.Host + "/some_page.php");
```

Comment: Take a look at [official sample](https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx/src/tip/GeckoFxTest/Main.cs). It has `TestModifyingDom` method, which changes BODY text. I believe you can change FRAME's `src` attribute the same way

Comment: To change the attributes in the frame, not necessarily to use TestModifyingDom `GeckoElement frame = geckoBrowser.Document.GetElementsByName("main")[0];
frame.SetAttribute("src", url);` But this is a bad solution, as for me

Comment: It seems, i found solutions
`Gecko.DOM.GeckoFrameElement frame = (Gecko.DOM.GeckoFrameElement)geckoBrowser.Document.GetElementsByName("main")[0]; 
    frame.Src = "http://" + webBrowser.Url.Host + "/" + url;`

Comment: Isn't `.SetAttribute("src", url)` and `.Src = url` essentially the same thing?

Comment: Yes,  it's same operation, but different way.